# How to enhance AMP page for Google Search

Tags: amp-html

"How to enhance my AMP page in google search.
For Example I have search Jeans,T-shirt etc... in google search bar but does't display my AMP pages.
So how to enhance my AMP search result for Google search."

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Google recommends to include structured data to your page (Schema.org in the JSON-LD or Microdata format). In case you are selling products, [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product) you find how to do this.